Is moving a public property to base class a breaking change in a public API
I ran into a problem I have not seen before.
I'm using a 3rd party assembly that comes in two different versions. I compile against one of them and load the correct version at runtime.
The version I compiled against looks like (V2.0.0)
public class A { public int P2 { get; set; } }
public class B : A { public int P1 { get; set; } }

The one I loaded at runtime looks like (V1.0.0)
public class A { public int P1 { get; set; } public int P2 { get; set;} }
public class B : A { }

The code in the calling assembly looks like
public static void Main() {
    var b = new B();
    b.P2 = 3;
}

To my surprise b.P2 fails with V1.0.0 loaded at runtime.
Intuitively I can sort of understand it. The compiled version has a reference to B::P2 which does not exist but it also seems strange since B::P2 is in the public API of B and that it happens to be implemented in A::P2 is a detail which shouldn't (or I was hoping it shouldn't) matter.
I can of course solve it by "recompiling" against the correct version but then I assume the problem will be with V2.0.0 instead.
Is there a way to avoid having 2 versions of my application?
If it matters, the 3rd party assembly is .NetFramework and my code is DotNet 8.
Edit: Sorry I got the classes wrong.
V1.0.0 looks like this
public class B { public int P1 { get; set; } public int P2 { get; set;} }

This means that the from the view of version compiled with V2.0.0 , the method moved to a more derived class (from A to B). In the document @canton7 linked this seems to be a breaking change.
But it also means that compiling with V1.0.0 and loading V2.0.0 should work since

adding a base class without abstract/virtual members is allowed.
moving member to base classes is allowed.

I learned that when compiling, you get a reference to the (base-)class where a member is defined even if you call access it through a derived class' public interface.

When you access B.P2, that's a direct, non-virtual call to the method B::get_P2(). If that method doesn't exist in the method table for B (as it won't if it's moved to A), that's going to cause a runtime failure

Interestingly, this doc says "ALLOWED: Moving a member into a class higher in the hierarchy than the type from which it was removed"

thanks @canton7, your comment had me take a closer look and saw I made an error, see the edit. With the document you linked I now know why I get the error (even if I still don't understand why the compiled reference is to the base instead of the class on which the call is made, but I'm sure there is good reason)
